# I am not getting difference between ($(cat)) and ${arr[@]}

Tags: linux, bash, unix

While I was solving problems I found out `($(cat))` and `${arr[@]}` with something different. Can anyone please explain what the difference is?

```
#!/bin/bash

read
arr=($(cat))

# read line
# arr=( $line )

arr=${arr[@]}
echo $((${arr// /^}))
```

Also, why commented section also works as `arr=($(cat))`?? or is there also a difference? If possible give one more example so that my concept will be clear.

Comment: That's a couple of questions in one.... why not try and make it separate questions? Those could be answered much more precisely.

Comment: They do two very different things. `$(cat)` expands to the contents of standard input, minus the first line. `$line` simply expands to the contents of the first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arr=($(cat))
```

populates an array while

```
arr=${arr[@]}
```

populates a scalar variable.

```sh
printf '%s %s\n'  a b c d > file
arr=($(cat file))
scalar=${arr[@]}

echo "${arr[1]}"  # b
echo "$scalar"    # a b c d
```